# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

- in my codebase I am getting this error  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at this line that.playerAdd();
- I tried to fix it by giving return true and putting if conditions .
- i even used on method
- nothing is working.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- if I keep breakpoint at this line that.playerAdd(); its not moving out of this line.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below

  ADD NEW

  ```
  $("#swimming").unbind().on('click', function() {
        if(true)
        {
          that.playerAdd();
        }
        return true;
      });

    playerAdd(): any {
      if(true) {
        $('#swimming').trigger('click');
      }
      return true;
    }


    http://jsfiddle.net/ejv7k9sn/2/
  ```

Comment: because the click event calls itself?

Comment: Thanks for your reply... can you tell me how to fix it

Comment: don't call itself?

Comment: Can you update in my code...it's so confusing

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Your click code calls player add and your playerAdd calls the button you clicked....

Comment: And those if statements do nothing, it is not like they are even there. I am not sure what you think they do.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `Maximum call stack size exceeded` because your function is an infinite loop. `if(true)` will always be true, so your first handler will always call `that.playerAdd();`. And again, `if(true)` will always remain true, therefore `$('#swimming').trigger('click');` will always be called. This will happen an infinite amount of times, and the maximum call stack size will run out. You must change your functions to not trigger each other every time.

What you change these to is deterministic on what you want your program to do, because as of now, it is very difficult to tell what exactly your end goal is. If you post a bit more code, or details about what you would like this to do we can probably be of more help.